# How possible is this project using Drupal

Tags: drupal, module, project

The aim of my project is to create an online help-centre for my company...

what I want is the following,

a "front page" for any user to use where there is a search area containing a field to search for questions (that autocompletes as the user types), and a drop down menu to select a help area "technical", "sales", "HR", "Payroll" etc... - this should default to All Areas.

Underneath this search area I want an area where the top 5 asked questions are displayed OR if the user has selected a help area the top 5 questions within that help area are displayed OR if the user has entered a question the related questions are displayed. In each case, i want it so the user can click on a question to display the answer in a light-box type pop-up.

These two boxes along with a welcome title and logo are all that is to be displayed...

I also want to have a backend where a registered user must login to access. Once logged in, the backend should be tabbed.

One tab will be for "Content Management" where users with this permission can add/edit/delete content - similar layout to the front end. The user will be able to search as in the front end except this time the question/answer/tags etc are displayed in fields that can be edited..

One tab will be for "Content Approval" where users with this permission can scroll through each change made by a "content manager" and either approve or reject the change - similar layout to the front end with a side area that is used as a change request inbox?

One tab will be for "Reporting" and another for "System Settings" - again I want similar layouts

This is the basics of what I want to achieve - how possible is this with Drupal given I have experience with PHP, JavaScript, and XHTML and a basic understanding of how drupal works?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: very possible

That all sounds doable, but if you haven't been developing in drupal, then there's a bit of a learning curve.  It will certainly require some custom module development, but once you get familiar with the Drupal API, it will be very rewarding.

All the source code is there.  If you see an interface that provides similar elements, just look at the module code and copy/modify it over to your modules.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, yes, it's possible, but this is not Drupal's focus field. Your demands would lead me to a framework-driven solution - there are a number of strong frameworks (if you need to use PHP, [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) and the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) should be good tools, if it does not need to be PHP, I personally would recommend the wonderful [Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/)).

As Coder1 said, developing such an application (and this is more a web application than a website) requires some knowledge in programming and Drupal module development. So if you will extend the project with a lot of content management stuff, do it with Drupal. If not, realize it using a framework, which will probably be done much faster.